# Reason for 5 sec delay to show an activity on pressing the home button?

Tags: android-widget, android-sdk-2.1

I am facing delay of 5 sec to show an Activity after pressing the HOME key. I had gone through some post and found that after pressing the HOME button, android prevents services and broadcast-receivers from calling startActivity for 5 seconds.

Q1. Can anyone please let me know the reason to happening this delay ?

Q2. When I modified the ActivityManagerService::checkAppSwitchAllowedLocked() to always return true, it avoids checking lock and hence Activity gets shown without any delay. Would it be a good solution to avoid delay or it may cause any wrong effect in other ways ?

Comment: I have used the permission in AndroidManifest.xml of my app as:

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.STOP_APP_SWITCHES"/>

but still its getting delayed by 5 secs.

Comment: Have you found the solution for this?

Answer (score 3):

I know, it's probably too late (half year passed). However, here is the answer

- You won't be able to get this permission on not rooted phone, unless your application is signed with the same keys as system. Android has some permissions like that.
- Also, you may be interested to check this question. [Starting an activity from a service after HOME button pressed without the 5 seconds delay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5600084/starting-an-activity-from-a-service-after-home-button-pressed-without-the-5-seco)