# How does Facebook Chat heads detect a home/menu press?

Tags: java, android, facebook

I've been trying to implement a service that displays UI similar to how facebook chatheads work. I noticed that I can detect a backpress inside of the View but I am unable to detect home presses.

I played around with the facebook chat head and I noticed that they're able to handle home presses and recent activity button presses seemlessly.

I've read this post: [Detect 'home button pressed' event in android service displaying a UI (similar to facebook chatheads)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18103091/detect-home-button-pressed-event-in-android-service-displaying-a-ui-similar-t)

but it does not seem to help

How do you detect it?

Comment: Can you be more specific about how your solution isn't working?

Comment: I current cannot detect any user home presses. My current implementation is an overlay using the Window Manager done in a Service. This, I believe, is how facebook chatheads is implemented.

Comment: Methods I have tried:

- I have tried to override View.onCloseSystemDialogs, but I was unsuccessful.
- Overrode View.dispatchKeyevent. I was only able to get a "back" key press. I need to also get home and recent button key presses.

Answer (score 1):

Hi have you tried registering a BroadcastReceiver to listen to this particular intent Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS. This will be called whenever android needs to remove temporary dialogs from the screen when home or recent apps key is pressed you can register a receiver with this intent to detect Home and Recent Apps key

Comment: @Daniel Happy to help :)