# How to listen home key in service?

Tags: android, key, android-service, listener, android-homebutton

I created a simple app demo and created a layout in my service class.
In the service class, I created a layout and I need to hide this layout when the user clicks on the home key.

I found sample [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18103091/detect-home-button-pressed-event-in-android-service-displaying-a-ui-similar-t) and implemented `setOnKeyListener` and `setOnFocusChangeListener` but not happen when clicked on home button.

My service class code:

```
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
        WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL |
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT
        );
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.service_layout, null);
        view.setFocusable(true);
        wm.addView(view, params);

        view.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                Log.i("FROM", "HOME OR OTHER KEY PRESSED");
                return false;
            }
        });

        view.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                Log.i("FROM", "HOME OR OTHER KEY PRESSED");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Listen to the broadcast:

```
public class HomeWatcherReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private static final String SYSTEM_DIALOG_REASON_KEY = "reason";
    private static final String SYSTEM_DIALOG_REASON_HOME_KEY = "homekey"

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (action.equals(Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS)) {

            String reason = intent.getStringExtra(SYSTEM_DIALOG_REASON_KEY);

            if (SYSTEM_DIALOG_REASON_HOME_KEY.equals(reason)) {

                //homekey

            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Im not in home now .in manifest XML need to add action or not ?

Comment: need to add XML
 <receiver android:name="com.mengdd.hellohome.HomeWatcherReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

Comment: i added to my project but not work still . i'm upload test app please help me i need that. www.amozkade.ir/TsetHomeButtonService.rar

Comment: It is not working in case of hardware home key is pressed... Do any one know that how to achieve that scenario!