# Android Delays when starting Activity from another app

Tags: android, android-activity

I have 2 apps.
App A and App B has only BActivity ( App B's Package is : com.ts.share).
From App A , i'd like to start App B. 
In App A, i called

```
Intent LaunchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.ts.share");
            LaunchIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity( LaunchIntent );
```

It worked fine.

At B, If exit B, go to A, and call again. It took 0s to start App B.

But At B, press Home button, go to A, and call again. It took 3 s to start App B.

I want to App B start immediately.

I appreciate your help!

Comment: This can't be handled via java code. This Intent runs outside of the application.

Comment: Create a button in A App, put above code on button click listenner. Thanks

Comment: I think you misunderstood the point I'm trying to make.

Comment: Is there a solution to improve it?

Comment: Like I said, you can't handle it programmatically.

Comment: This defect is a feature of Android OS.
To prevent untrusted starting activity call.
There is a bug report here
[[https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=4536]]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Starting an activity from a service after HOME button pressed without the 5 seconds delay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5600084/starting-an-activity-from-a-service-after-home-button-pressed-without-the-5-seco)

Answer (score 0):

In your second scenario, B is already running when you start it from A. In this case, because you've specified `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVIY_CLEAR_TOP`, it will need to finish the existing Activities that are still active in B before it can instantiate a new Activity in B. It is possible that you have code in `finish()`, `onPause()`, `onStop()`, or `onDestroy()` of the Activity (or Activities) in B that is causing the 3 seccond delay.

Answer (score -1):

try this..

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
    Intent LaunchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.ts.share");
    LaunchIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity( LaunchIntent );
    }
}, 0);
```

Comment: Thanks, But Nothing Changed! Still delay.

Answer (score -1):

It may be possible that your main thread is doing much work. An alternative solution would also be to load the intent on a separate handler.

```
Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

handler.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Intent LaunchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.ts.share");
            LaunchIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity( LaunchIntent );
    }
});
```