# Reduce time between context.startActivity and onCreate method of this activity

Tags: android

I'm developing an application which must start activity when screen of device turns off. I use the BroadcastReceiver with intent filter, and in my receiver I call:

```
startActivity(new Intent(MyService.this, FullscreenActivity.class)
   .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS));
```

The problem is onCreate of my FullscreenActivity begins after 5 seconds after startActivity method call! 5 seconds, Carl! But it happens not every time. For example, if I turn screen off from the desctop, it works immediately. But if some fullscreen application is running, pushing the home button and then pushing the power button makes the 5 seconds delay.

```
09-13 11:55:32.658  28608-28608/com.incodemobile.incodeandroid.mylocker D/333﹕ Screen off
09-13 11:55:32.658  28608-28608/com.incodemobile.incodeandroid.mylocker D/333﹕ activity started from receiver BEGIN
09-13 11:55:32.698  28608-28608/com.incodemobile.incodeandroid.mylocker D/333﹕ activity started from receiver END
09-13 11:55:37.022  28608-28608/com.incodemobile.incodeandroid.mylocker D/333﹕ oncreate activity start
09-13 11:55:37.673  28608-28608/com.incodemobile.incodeandroid.mylocker D/333﹕ oncreate activity end
```

Is it possible to reduce this time?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Starting an activity from a service after HOME button pressed without the 5 seconds delay](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5600084/starting-an-activity-from-a-service-after-home-button-pressed-without-the-5-seco)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a hardcoded delay of 5 seconds after pressing the home button, to ensure a user always has a way to escape from an application and get back to the home screen.

You can read more [at this issue post](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=4536), it is an undocumented safety mechanism that is not likely to ever be changed, and cannot be worked around by third party applications.