# start an activity from service after user presses home button within 5 seconds

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service

How to start an activity from service when user press home button. As mentioned in this feature that for 5 seconds the activity cannot be started: [link](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=4536)

I want to start the activity when user taps on it.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Starting an activity from a service after HOME button pressed without the 5 seconds delay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5600084/starting-an-activity-from-a-service-after-home-button-pressed-without-the-5-seco)

Answer (score 0):

To run after a specified time, you can use the following code to do:

```
new CountDownTimer(5000, 1000){
@Override
public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished){}

@Override
public void onFinish(){

// Your code run after 5 second...


}
}.start();
```